# Input value in a textbox base on the value of another textbox

Tags: ms-access

I'm new in access database.  I have a form which the user have to input data. I have two textbox (wbc and txt1). wbc is a bound textbox while txt1 is unbound textbox. Wbc values must be between certain range I.e between 3.5 and 9.5. I want that if the user input a value below 3.5 then txt1 show the text 'Low' automatically or if wbc contains a value greater than 9.5 then txt1 show the text  'high'. But if wbc value is between 3.5 and 9.5 then txt1 will show nothing. I don't know how to go about this. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a macro to the AfterUpdate event on Wbc.

This macro checks the value of Wbc and changes the value of txt1 if Wbc violates the rules you mentioned

[Macro image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIA4M.png)

Comment: Thanks BankBuiler. I will try it but I I just remembered the form a subform of a main form

Comment: BankBuilder  the macros worked so well. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm glad to hear it